# Livejournal OpenID authentication is broken

Tags: support, status-completed, openid

I was not able to create a new account on the new [Gadgets](http://gadgets.stackexchange.com) site with my livejournal.com OpenID; I get this error from the authentication screen (after being redirected to LJ):

> The site you just came from seems to want to verify an identity  that you, as <LJ username>, cannot provide.

(I also have the same problem with a SE site that just started its private beta.)

<sub>(This is probably not related to my other problem, just filed with team@..., regarding not being on the private beta list when I should be.)</sub>

---

**UPDATE:** Livejournal OpenID logins are now working again.

Comment: I had this exact problem on ODATA this morning, so it isn't JUST SE.

Comment: Agreed, I just tried serverfault (the only site in the tetrology where I wasn't logged in) and it is likewise broken; updated title.

Comment: I'm having this problem with Stack Overflow and Stack Overflow Meta now. Funnily, this was my first login attempt after I added a secondary OpenID to my Stack Overflow account yesterday, so I thought it was that that messed things up, but now I see that it's not just me!

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Looks like LJ made some OpenID changes recently: http://community.livejournal.com/lj_releases/59530.html

Comment: They note that this is a bug in a recent post to the lj_support community: http://community.livejournal.com/lj_support/811222.html

Comment: I can confirm this.  It's affecting all my accounts, so I had to create temp accounts (including this one), and I've asked that they be merged so I can log in through delegation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has to be a change on LiveJournal side; we haven't changed anything on our end.

I'll check into it.

Update courtesy of [Andrew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/46926/andrew-arnott):

> LiveJournal.com has been a poor OpenID implementation.  I forgot what the specifics were.  But now, when I type in my OpenID of http://example.livejournal.com/ they respond with an identifier_select OP Identifier, which they later fail to auhenticate.  This is a LiveJournal bug. :(
>
> LJ bug filed:
>   http://www.livejournal.com/support/see_request.bml?id=1131697&auth=9zce

Comment: LJ is working again; this question can be marked **[status-completed]**.

Answer (score 2):

Reproduced:

> ## Error
>
> The site you just came from seems to want to verify an identity that you, as [**shog9**](http://shog9.livejournal.com/), cannot provide.

However, delegating to a LJ ID still works just fine. Comparing the URLs of the successful delegation and unsuccessful direct attempts shows that the identity *is* being set to "http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select" in the latter case, which of course is not my identity. Perhaps LJ is doing better input-checking on requests now?

Comment: @Sog9: what do you mean by delegating to a LJ ID? How is this different than providing a LJ URL as an OpenId?

Comment: @Ether: I pass shog9.com as the openID to the gadgets site, which reads my LJ ID and the delegation links to LJ from the markup and proceeds to authenticate with LJ. But passing the LJ ID directly fails... Possibly because the site tries to pass `identity=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select` as my identity... ( [view source](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/6b8aaaf0-2fed-46db-be5d-db497c6924d2/view-source) on this answer)

Comment: Perhaps this is the kick in the ass I need to set up delegation from my vanity domain!

Comment: @Ether: DO IT! The time you save not typing, ".livejournal.com" will more than make up for whatever effort it takes to upload a new default page.

Comment: Nah, I just click on the LJ icon and type the first letter of my username to get it to be auto-filled. The only annoying part is typing the full name on the first site I log into, after restarting my browser.

Comment: Btw, i the ame problem is in publicauth app for django. Maybe, LJ switched standarts?

Comment: RE: "Perhaps LJ is doing better..."
No.  LJ is checking their inputs and failing on perfectly valid inputs -- inputs that LJ itself in fact is causing the RP to generate.

Comment: @Andrew: beats me; delegating to LJ still works, so I'm happy.

Comment: Yes, using delegation produces a different result in the discovery step that causes a differently formed auth request to go to LJ, so that's why that still works.  It's just the LJ-hosted OpenIDs that have the problem when you use them directly.

Answer (score 1):

Worse than that, I have a secondary OpenID registered and accounts on Meta, ServerFault and SuperUser associated with it, and now it is a crapshoot to which site I can login with that alternate OpenID (which I since made the primary).

Sometimes its StackOverflow, others it is ServerFault...

If I associate the accounts, then shouldn't the secondary OpenIDs be valid?

ALSO, I did go to the account I managed to login, with the (now) primary OpenID not being the LJ one, I did *Copy profile to all associated accounts* and I still cannot login using that other OpenID on the other accounts...

I think this shows that identity on the stack exchange sites needs to be more closely tied *at least* with regards with the openID used, *if the accounts get associated*.

UPDATE: Holly crap... My secondary OpenID at claimid is now *different* from when I first used it, and instead of claimid.com/njsf it is now openid.claimid.com/njsf which makes the stack exchange sites think it is a different identity. WHAT A MESS!

Comment: so email the address at the bottom of every web page and we'll help you get this sorted.

Answer (score 0):

I use livejournal as well and I'm getting this error on stack overflow when I try to log into my already existing account.

In the URL being passed to LJ my identity is identity=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select. I tried changing it around to various things, putting in http://xxxx.livejournal.com/ does return to stack overflow. Unfortunately I am then greeted with the following:

Unable to log in with your OpenID provider:

The following required parameters were missing from the PositiveAssertionResponse message: dnoa.op_endpoint

Comment: identity should be a link to stackoverflow