# LiveJournal Login : No OpenID endpoint found

Tags: bug, openid, login

I am unable to login through live journal account getting following error

> Unable to log in with your OpenID provider:
>
> No OpenID endpoint found.

[image]

What is issue?

Comment: Perhaps not a dupe, but something similar has been reported before: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57928/livejournal-openid-authentication-is-broken Might be relevant?

Comment: LiveJournal says that the journal in your screenshot isn't registered, are you sure you typed in your username correctly?